# Play sound file after orientation switches [Android Studio]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, android-studio-3.0, android-orientation

My program is supposed to play a sneeze and a blowing nose sound. If the button for the sneeze sound is clicked, it will be played. After this, if the device gets rotated, it should play the blow nose sound (vice versa for the blow nose button). I have been trying to use onSaveInstance and onRestoreInstance but none of them is working. Is there anything that I am missing?

Here is my current code on the main activity:

```
package com.example.togglemediaplayer;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MediaPlayer sneezeSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sneeze2);
        final MediaPlayer blowSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.blow_nose);

        Button sneeze = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sneezeButton);
        sneeze.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sneezeSound.start();
            }
        });

        Button blow = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.blowButton);
        blow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                blowSound.start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I have also added the config change in the manifest file
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Answer (score 0):

You can catch rotate event in this method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes I was able to use this and restructure my code to make it work!